# UserDefined Function is not working any more in document db

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am using Microsoft Azure DocumentDB Client Library for managing document db.
However recently all my user defined functions stopped working.
In order to test the functionality I tried this simple user defined function,

I can create user defined function using

```
var udf = new UserDefinedFunction
            {
                Id = "Tax",
                Body = "function(value) { return value * .2;} ",
            };
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.CreateUserDefinedFunctionAsync(colSelfLink, udf)
```

However when i use the udf in my sql query i get a error saying

> Tax is not a recognized built-in function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DocumentDB now requires a case-sensitive "udf." prefix for user defined functions within queries - e.g., "SELECT udf.TAX(d.SalesAmount) FROM docs d". The older syntax has been deprecated. This was done for a couple of reasons

- To add support for built-in functions and clearly disambiguate them from user defined functions
- For a similar programming experience with ANSI-SQL which requires a schema name, e.g., "dbo." for user defined functions